# Rails application with javascript and xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have a rails application and am trying to print some values (that are stored in xml files) with javascript.

Javascript is working fine, but when it tries to reference the xml file I get this in the console: GET http:// somethingsomething/appwiki/register.xml 404 (Not Found)

I've tried putting the xml files into all the different folders but it doesnt work...

Comment: Can you show us your `routes.rb` file & `controller` code to display the `xml` files? If they're static XML files, can you tell us in which folder you've stored them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not prefered to read and parse files on the client side.  If you really wanted to achieve that, then make sure you server the file with the asset pipeline just like images/css/js.

What would be considered a better approach is parse the XML on the server side with [Nokogirl](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html), then using the display variable to show what is needed.